# Express Server seems to give 200 then gives 404 on post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am teaching myself NodeJS to create an application, and I'm running into a problem with Express where the server seems to return a 200 code on a post request, but then immediately becomes a 404 for some reason.

The request was properly handled before I added a jquery method in between the client and server to do some front-end verification first. Before, I simply just
included "action='/login'" as an attribute for the form tag and it worked.

I am using the express generator

Here's how the form info looks like (in Jade):

```
form(name="logins" id="loginfo" role="form" method="post")
```

It is handled by this function in welcome-screen.js, located in a static directory which I've specified in app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginfo").submit(function(event, done) {
        checkEmail();
    });
});

function checkEmail() {
    var email = document.forms["logins"]["usrname"].value;
    console.log(email);
    if (email.length != 0) {
        getLogin(email);
    }
}

function getLogin(email) {
    $.post("/login", {"usrname" : email});
}
```

Here's the server code which handles the post request on "/login". The console shows the print statements, so I know that the request is making it to the server and that "/login" can be found.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
....
router.post("/login", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body["usrname"]);
    var user = req.body["usrname"];
    res.render("login", {title : "Hello!",
                    username : user});
    console.log("Passed rendering");
});
```

However, I am redirected to the default error page giving me a 404 error.

Here is the stack trace I got, if it helps anyone.

```
Error: Not Found
    at D:\projects\neg5\app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]      (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
at next (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
at Function.handle (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
at router (D:\projects\neg5\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

After I send the post request, the console prints these two lines included in the express generator, so I know that "/login" is being found.

```
POST /login 200 34.463 ms - 598
POST / 404 25.479 ms - 1398
```

I've been pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your code on GitHub? Try my suggestion below and if it doesn't work, can I take a look at the whole project?

Comment: That fix didn't solve it :( Is there any way I can send it to you without putting the url here? I'm using bitbucket for this project

Comment: It's telling me I need 20 reputation to talk in that room

Comment: What should I post there?

Comment: The link to your repo (if you want to share)

Comment: Here you go: https://onetimesecret.com/secret/ctjed6v8mg72cq6khku8iv3d950gn55

Thank you for the help!

Comment: thanks, and no problem. I do have one suggestion for you: add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore`. Your repo has almost 3000 files because you're including all the dependencies.

Comment: I'll definitely do that, thanks. As soon as I get this figured out

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, but I think I have it figured out. Give me a second, let me see if I can send you a pull request with bitbucket

Comment: No problem! The 404 problem is gone, but the conditional in my checkEmail() function just seems to be skipped over. Could you explain what you had to do? I'm not sure how the page is going to "/login" without that route having a post handler in index.js

Comment: I should have been more clear, my apologies. What I want to do is do front end validation first. If that passes, only then will I actually send a post request to the server. Right now, checkEmail() seems to ignore the "length != 0" conditional and posts no matter what

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Turns out your conditional isn't being ignored (it won't post if it's empty). Try removing the checkEmail call; the page still refreshes when you hit submit.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can't believe I overlooked something that simple haha. You'll want to change the login route handler back to `/login` btw. I'll send you a PR on bitbucket so you can view the diff.

Comment: Awesome, the 404 error is gone! Thank you so much for the help!

One more question (somewhat unrelated): Do you know the best way to do front-end validation for something like this? In the way I have it right now, a post request is immediately sent to the server after clicking submit, so there's no FE-validation going on.

Comment: @mbhuiyan, for my understanding, you want to check email and then login. but you trigger login post after click submit button. the submit will raise another POST. so you actually send two POST request. that is why you got two lines outputs.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I understand now why I got two lines of post requests. That still leaves me with a problem, though. Whenever I click submit, the form will post because of the form's attributes action and method. However, I want to check the info the user has typed in before I even talk to the server. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that? Would I need to get rid of the method and action attrs in the form tag and call post somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `action="/login"` to your login form (in `views/index.jade`), like so:

```
form(name="logins" id="loginfo" action="/login" role="form" method="post")
    // rest of view omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /login 200 34.463 ms - 598
POST / 404 25.479 ms - 1398
```

this tells two requests had been sent, one is /login, another is /.

```
   POST /login 200 is trigger by code $.post()
   POST/ 404  is triggered by code $.submit()
```